# Framework Ignore List pattern for node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, react-native, chrome-debugging

Within chrome debugger, during a React Native debugging session, I can ignore individual files by right-clicking in the Source file editor and selecting `Add script to ignore list`. Not an optimal solution.

I know that I can exclude folders using a pattern in the Framework Ignore List (Settings > Ignore List). Not being regex-savvy, I looked for an existing example without success. Can someone provide a tested example of how to ignore all libraries not related to the project source code, specifically the `/node_modules` folder?

Comment: UPDATE: Surprisingly, this question has remained unanswered. In the meantime, Google has once again changed the name. It is under `Settings > Blackboxing`. Either I'm asking in the wrong place, or I've stumbled on debugging greatest enigma.

Comment: I read you question 5 times, even with my friend, I cannot understand, what you want? your question is not clear at all. what's the main problem, please leave the solution of your solution, what is the main, root problem. It's so weird for me. why you care about `node_modules`? it's for development area. for production the bundle will be a transpiled file with no containing `node_modules`.

Comment: I don't care about `node_modules`, I wan't the debugger to ignore them. Currently, it steps through all files including my source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution would be to ignore every file which contains `/node_modules/` in its path. You can do this with the pattern `.*\/node_modules\/.*`.